# SQL UNION - illogical results

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, union

I have an interesting problem with UNION in SQL.

My Statement is of this form:

```
with tab as (
(select FldA, FldB From  Table1A inner join Table1B on Field1A=Field1B)
UNION
(select FldA, FldB From  Table2A inner join Table2B on Field2A=Field2B)
)
select * from tab
where FldA="XYZ"
```

When I run this, I get only 1 row returned - which is not correct. I can verify it's not correct just by commenting the UNION and second Select statement:

```
with tab as (
(select FldA, FldB From  Table1A inner join Table1B on Field1A=Field1B)
--UNION
--(select FldA, FldB From  Table2A inner join Table2B on Field2A=Field2B)
)
select * from tab
where FldA="XYZ"
```

If I run this version, I get **THREE** rows returned! I assume I'm doing something stupid - but I can't imagine what.

Comment: i assume the 3 rows have the same fldA,fldB values in the second query. As you are using `union` it eliminated duplicates and the result would be one row for the first query.

Comment: The obvious issue would be if the three rows have identical `FldA` and `FldB` values - `UNION` eliminates duplicates.

Answer (score 7):

`UNION` removes duplicates, to keep duplicates use `UNION ALL`.

In this sense, `UNION` works the same as `DISTINCT`. As with `DISTINCT` records are considered duplicates if the records are identical for every (selected) column.

`UNION` removes duplicates regardless of in which set the duplicates occur, since the `DISTINCT` is executed after the `UNION`.

If you have 2 queries/data sets `A` and `B`, if you `UNION` these together, you get the `DISTINCT` combination of both. If there are duplicates in `A` they are removed. If a record exists in `A` and in `B`, it is also returned uniquely (i.e., it only occurs once in your final result set).

Comment: Excellent! Thank you, this worked perfectly. Will mark as the answer as soon as it lets me. I assumed UNION was giving me all rows in both Selects, but it clearly isn't.

Answer (score 3):

`union` removes duplicates from the result. A common "gotcha" with it is that it removes **any** duplicates from the results, regardless of whether they're duplicate between the two result sets or within any one of the result sets.

If you need to preserve these duplicates, you could use `union all` instead.

Comment: If tableA has duplicates, When I `UNION` it with tableB, Does the duplicates in tableA will be removed in the result set?

Comment: Thank you - this answer is more complete but I feel I need to mark HoneyBadger's as the answer as it was first.